# Creating features from JSON without writing to disk first using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, json

In ArcPy, I want to use [JSONToFeatures_conversion](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/conversion-toolbox/json-to-features.htm), but I'm working with data that I pulled from a web service. I have no need to save the data to disk. So, I thought I could do something like this:

```
fd = StringIO.StringIO(<my JSON string>)
arcpy.JSONToFeatures_conversion(fd, 'in_memory\\output')
```

arcpy definitely doesn't like that though. I'm considering using the tempfile module, but that's not an ideal solution for this. Temp files aren't really a good solution for this because of a few factors, from environmental constraints (permissions in some of the environments where it may run) to the size of the datasets (IO overhead).

doing this:

```
fs = arcpy.FeatureSet()
fs.load(<url to service>)
```

Isn't exactly ideal either because the dataset is composed of data from a couple sources, with different attributes that have to be reconciled.

Ultimately, the product of this operation will be passed in to [arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/select-layer-by-location.htm) as the select_features parameter

Environment: ArcMap 10.x (multiple machines running slightly different versions, but none of it's ArcGIS Pro, hence all Python2 not Python3)

Comment: The `in_memory` object is a **table** emulator; it does not support files. Creating temp files/folders in a GP service is trivial, and Server will clean them up after the process finishes execution.

Comment: You could also have a look at `arcpy.AsShape`, but it only supports individual geometries, not features or feature collections, i.e. `{"type": "PointLineOrPolygon", "coordinates": [etc...]}`

Comment: Thanks, but temp files really aren't ideal for this. I tried arcpy.AsShape, but the output is a featureset, and can't be passed into later processing tools such as arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management

Comment: Does copy features work on feature set?

Comment: AsShape returns a geometry object and you can use CopyFeatures on a list of geometries.  Or if you have other info in the json aside from the coordinates then store those that a separate list and use a cursor to insert them into a feature class

Comment: What do you mean by, "arcpy definitely doesn't like that"?

Comment: @mikewatt (and others who suggested using AsShape), I think that was what I needed. I didn't realize CopyFeatures would accept a list of geometries.

Answer (score 0):

As [commented by @mikewatt](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/318542/creating-features-from-json-without-writing-to-disk-first-using-arcpy#comment518567_318542):

> AsShape returns a geometry object and you can use CopyFeatures on a
> list of geometries. Or if you have other info in the json aside from
> the coordinates then store those that a separate list and use a cursor
> to insert them into a feature class.